# Microsoft office and SharePoint Vulnerability

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, patching

could you please help me with below listd SharePoint Vulnerability? what are all these updates ? how to fix these Vulnerability? if i do update or apply patch does it effect my sharepoint farm or site or applications?

Please any help suggestion solution will be very helpfull.

1.Microsoft Office and Microsoft Office Services and Web Apps Security Update May 2019

2.Microsoft SharePoint Foundation and SharePoint Server Update August 2020

3.Microsoft Office Remote Code Execution Vulnerability (MS17-014)

4.EOL/Obsolete Software: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP0) RTM Detected

5.Microsoft Visual Studio Security Update for July 2018

6.Microsoft Word and Office Web Apps Remote Code Execution Vulnerability (MS14-017)

7.Microsoft SharePoint Server Elevation of Privilege Vulnerability (MS15-036)

8.Microsoft Skype for Business Denial of Service Vulnerability

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you got above list from your security team's scanning result?

Anyway, you should be able to get a fix related to above vulnerability by search them on Internet. Each of them already have a patch to handle that particular vulnerability.

- Security Update May 2019 properly means you need to apply SharePoint patch later than May 2019.
- MS17-014 is the Microsoft Security Bulletin number. Just download it and apply according to instruction
- RTM Detected : means your SQL server edition is too old. You need to apply the latest service pack
- Microsoft Skype have changed name to Lync. You may refer to [this page](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2018-8546) and select the patch fit your environment

> if i do update or apply patch does it effect my sharepoint farm or site or applications?

Yes. It may affect your SharePoint and applications. You need to test the patches in a test environment before apply to production.

Comment: Thanks Mark.. Few Clarification like I have not done any update or patch from 2016 . IS now i need to apply every patch month wise and year wise or only alone just latest CU 2020 update will remedies for previous all patch updates ? Below are few list  i have pasted for your understanding .Example :                                                                                       Microsoft Office and Microsoft Office Services and Web Apps Security Update November 2018 
Microsoft Office and Microsoft Office Services and Web Apps Security Update October 2018 Etc....................

Comment: You only need to apply the latest CU update (e.g. Oct 2020) because the patch is "cumulative". It contains all the previous updates.

Comment: Thank you so much :-)

Comment: Please mark as answer if it helps. Thanks.